# Angular 2 testing, template update not being detected

Tags: angular, angular2-testing

I am testing a component which dinamically inserts a checkbox in its template when ngAfterViewInit lifecycle hook is called.

```
export class MyComponent {

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // checkbox insertion in the template here
    ...
  }

  ...
}
```

This is my test:

```
it('should inject the checkbox', () => {
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AutogeneratedTableComponent);
  fixture.detectChanges();

  rows = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('tr'));
  console.log(Object.assign({}, rows[1].nativeElement));  // *referenceLog
  console.log(rows[1].nativeElement));  // *cloneLog

  expect(rows[1].query(By.css('input')).not.toBeNull(); // FAILS
}
```

*refereceLog (prints the tr without the inserted td)

```
<tr ng-reflect-id="22" id="22">
   <td>Single Room</td>
   <td>My single room.</td>
</tr>
```

*cloneLog (shows that at time of testing the template is not ready)

```
Object{__zone_symbol__eventTasks: [ZoneTask{zone: ..., runCount: ..., _zoneDelegates: ..., _state: ..., type: ..., source: ..., data: ..., scheduleFn: ..., cancelFn: ..., callback: ..., invoke: ...}]}
```

I tried manually calling ngAfterViewInit()

```
it('should inject the checkbox', () => {
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AutogeneratedTableComponent);
  fixture.detectChanges();

  fixture.debugElement.componentInstance.ngAfterViewInit();
  fixture.detectChanges();

  rows = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('tr'));
  console.log(Object.assign({}, rows[1].nativeElement));  // *referenceLog
  console.log(rows[1].nativeElement));  // *cloneLog

  expect(rows[1].query(By.css('input')).not.toBeNull(); // FAILS
}
```

*refereceLog (prints the expected tr)

```
<tr ng-reflect-id="22" id="22">
   <td><input id="22" type="checkbox"></td>
   <td>Single Room</td>
   <td>My single room.</td>
</tr>
```

No changes in *cloneLog

Then I tried

- Adding `spyOn(component,
  'ngAfterViewInit').andReturnValue(Promise.resolve(true)).and.callThrough();`
  and then `spyOn().calls.mostRecent.returnValue.then(() =>
  {fixture.detectChanges() ... })` with the `done()` at the bottom of
  the block
- Adding `async()` to the individual test declaration and doing the
  evaluation inside a `fixture.whenStable.then( () => {
  fixture.detectChanges()... } )`
- Adding `fakeAsync()` to the individual test declaration and a `tick()`
  calling before the evaluation

All the attempts with the same previous result. The template element is being updated after the evaluation is done.

I should find a way to stop the test execution until the nativeElement that I am testing is updated.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem and this solution worked for me:

I called `fixture.autoDetectChanges(true);` instead of (or additionally to) `fixture.detectChanges()`.

Comment: awesome, after several hours search landed on this answer. Could you also please point to any documentation where you found this suggestion? Thanks

Comment: Still valid for Angular 9 